# How to replace a certain letter with J as I sequence through the letters in the String obtained by the user

Tags: java

I need to make use of a for loop and sequence through a string given by the console. It needs to replace every occurrence of a letter as it sequences through. For example:
INPUT : Geese RESULT : Jeese GJJsJ GJJsJ GeeJe GJJsJ

I honestly have tried everything within the bounds of my java experience. I am lost.

Comment: Can you please share your code and dhow what happens as well ass how that differs from the expected output?

Comment: It's hard to give you a useful answer (as in, one you will learn from vs just handing over some code) because we don't know where the bounds of your Java experience lie. Please show what you have tried, and explain the problem you have that is stopping you getting the desired output.

Comment: Is the "RESULT" the actual output your program is giving, or the required result?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
    String input = "Geese";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ){
        System.out.println(input.replace(input.charAt(i), 'J'));
    }
```

It iterates over each char in string and then replaces all occurrences with letter 'J'.

[replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_replace.asp)
[charAt()](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_charat.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem.

It iterates through each character of the input string and for each character, it replaces all occurrences of that current character in the original string with the letter "J".

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input = scanner.next();
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    String output = input.replaceAll(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)), "J");
    System.out.print(output + " ");
  }
}
```

**Input:** "Geese"

**Output:** "Jeese GJJsJ GJJsJ GeeJe GJJsJ"